# Intercepting HTTP response body in DropWizard 0.7.0/Jersey 1.x

Tags: java, javascript, mustache, dropwizard, jersey-1.0

I'm building a web service with DropWizard 0.7.0 that produces JavaScript output using a Mustache template. I'd like to minify and obfuscate the generated JavaScript.

In Jersey 2.x's manual, I see that one can define [interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e8344), specifically [WriterInterceptor](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/$%7Bjaxrs.api.version%7D/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html)s, for manipulating HTTP response entities. This feels like the appropriate place for the minification/obfuscation as it should occur after the template has been applied. However, DW 0.7.0 uses Jersey 1.18.1.

I'm aware there's [a branch of DropWizard with Jersey 2.x support](https://github.com/saadmufti/dropwizard/tree/jersey-2), but I'm keen to use the standard DW distribution.

Is there a way of intercepting the response HTTP entity/body after a template has been applied using DW 0.7.0/Jersey 1.18.1?

Comment: Simply obfuscating the template won't work as the template isn't valid JS: it uses {{#loops}}. It's also impractical to remove Mustache markup from my template, obfuscate it and add markup back into the obfuscated version because it's far from obvious where my {{#loops}} should go in the obfuscated version!

Comment: Doesnt Servlet filters help in this case? (--> http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#servlet-filters) There you can validate the entire response body if you want.

Comment: I tried that, but Jetty was applying it after the body had been gzipped...

Comment: try ContainerResponseFilter. I think that is on Jersey level, so it won't be gzipped. Example -> http://blog.usul.org/cors-compliant-rest-api-with-jersey-and-containerresponsefilter/